# returning setTimeout returns 1 for some reason

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I'm trying to return setTimeout() that prints out "Hello" after .5 sec. It is returning an unwanted 1 before "Hello". Can anyone figure this out?

```js
let c = () => setTimeout(() => console.log("hello"), 500)
console.log(c()); //1
                  //hello
```

Answer (score 3):

You’re getting 1 because `setTimeout` returns its unique identifier which JS uses to identify the timeout.

This means when you `console.log(c())` you’re going to get the return of `setTimeout` which is its id.

To fix this, you can just call `c()` without logging its return value:

```js
const c = () => setTimeout(() => console.log("hello"), 500)
c(); // hello
```